# Using two sqlserver databases ,on the web hosting and the other in my local server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I hope some one tell me how tow connect to two SQL Server databases (same databases). The first one is on my web hosting, and the other one in my local server.

I'm using layers which data access layer (class) contains connection, select and execute commands for T-SQL.

Thanks

Comment: using two sqlserver database!!!!!!!!

Comment: You simply use the correct connection string for each one. Try that and post any specific questions